# URL: Username with @

Tags: http, url, url-encoding

To send username and password with a URL, we use this scheme:

```
http://username:password@www.my_site.com
```

But my username is `my_email@gmail.com`.
The problem is the `@`.

How can I solve it?

Comment: encode the `@` as `%40`.

Comment: You don't want to include a password in your URL's, because then you might accidentally try to access the URL via HTTP (which you are doing), and this means that anyone with Wireshark within 50 meters of you has your password and username.

Comment: The problem with using URL encoding in the username is that the HTTP client has to decode it before sending the username to the server. And though browsers seem to do that just fine, a lot of HTTP clients don't (and thus are broken). I can't believe how much of a mess it is considering it's 2021

Answer (score 241, accepted):

You need to URL encode the @ as %40.

Comment: Nice. This also works if your password contains an `@` too, which is increasingly likely with random passwords created by password managers.

Comment: do I have to do this with all characters different than alphanumeric? for example, if my username is `name.lastname@mail.com` and my password `abc!@#`, should I use `name%2Elastname%40mail%2Ecom` and `abc%21%40%23`?

Answer (score 26):

Just do:

```
 http://my_email%40gmail.com:password@www.my_site.com
```

I am quite surprised that problem was with username `@` and not the password -usually this is where I get reserved characters in url authority or path parts.

To solve general case of special characters: Just open chrome console with <kbd>F12</kbd> then paste  `encodeURIComponent(str)` where `str` is your password (or username) and then use the encoded result to form url with password.

Or just run the below snippet and dump it here.

```html
Put Url here
<br/>
<input type='text' id='urlEncodeField' style="width:250px" value='my_email@gmail.com' />
<input type='button' value='Click' onClick="console.log(encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('urlEncodeField').value))" />
```

Hope this saves you some time.

Answer (score 21):

Use %40 in your username instead of the @ symbol for the url encoding.  It should pass it properly then.

Comment: This works splendid now that bitbucket does not allow plain usernames any more, but requires username@example.org style usernames.