# How do you build a URL that contains a username and password from user input in Python?

Tags: python, url

I see you can parse usernames and passwords with:

```
from urlparse import urlparse
r = urlparse('http://myuser:mypass@example.com')
print r.username
# => 'myuser'
```

How can I go the other way? I can't use `urlunparse` because I can't do this:

```
r.username = request.args['username']
# => AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

I'm interested because the username contains characters that need escaped (namely: `@`, `/`).

**Edit:**

This string is coming from user input, so I won't know ahead of time what it is. It's a security risk to maintain your own list of escape characters, so string concatenation and custom character escaping with `replace` won't help here.

Comment: couldn't you do a simple `str.format(x,y,z)` before you set `r`?

Comment: @taesu No, the characters that need escaped won't get escaped that way. See my update.

Comment: @iAdjunct Writing your own copy of what needs escaped (and not maintaining it) is a security risk.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the username part of basic auth URLs [use the same escape characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050877/url-username-with) that query parameters do.

So the answer is to use `urllib.quote(username, safe='')` then concatenate. ([You'll need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695183/how-to-percent-encode-url-parameters-in-python) the `safe` parameter or `/` won't be escapted.)