# Set up proxy for scraping with nodejs using request and cheerio

Tags: node.js, proxy, web-scraping, cheerio, requestjs

I'm trying to set up a basic scraper using request and cheerio. The problem is that I need to GET the websites from different geos to monitor differences in the ads being displayed and the actual content. It was fairly easy to set it up without the proxy part, but when I add a proxy in the request options, it doesn't work (i.e: I get the content based on my actual location).

Just in case, this is totally for educational purposes.

This is the basic code I'm using (I'm a total newbie):

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require("cheerio");

request = request.defaults({jar: true});

var options = {
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110319 Firefox/3.6.16'
    },
    proxy: 'http://myusername@gmail.com:mypassword@proxy-provider's-URL'
};

request(options, function () {

    request('http://www.the-website-to-scrape.com', function (error, response, body) {

        var $ = cheerio.load(body);

        $("div").each(function(i, e) {
            var result= $(e).find('h3>a').text();
            console.log("Result: " + result);

        });
    });
});
```

Any ideas on how to make this work? This is my first question ever on stackoverflow and I've only started coding a couple months ago.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: may be problem with proxy url, why do you use 2 @ symbols there? Username can't contains @ symbol, it reserved in URI schema

Comment: I thought that could be the problem. In this case, my credentials for the proxy service are my-email:my-password, so there's an additional @ on my username.

Comment: encode it with %40, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050877/url-username-with

Comment: Still not working :-/ I get the same content with or without the proxy. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: curious, who are you using for a proxy provider?  I run a phantomjs service and am looking to add proxy support.

Comment: We're using Geosurf from Adclarity. Excellent service I must say.