# FInding an element without inspect option

Tags: selenium

[pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V80Nb.png)I came across a situation when an URL is opened it is giving a POP for login functionality. I am unable to find the inspect option for finding the elements.

Please help me in addressing this issue.
thanks
Akshay

Comment: upload screen shot here please

Comment: sure i have posted it as a popup.please look into this

Comment: That looks like a javascript pop up. Selenium cannot handle non-html pop-ups. You can pass user name and password in URL like [https://username:password@example.com](https://username:password@example.com)  this sends the credentials in the standard HTTP "Authorization" header or use 3rd party tools like AutoIT. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050877/url-username-with