# What if password has an '@' when using command line proxy at pip install?

Tags: python, proxy, pip

Trying to install a package using pip in which the network has a firewall and we needed to set a proxy on the command.

This is the syntax we followed:
`pip install --proxy=domain\username:passwd@proxy.address:port package_name`

But it fails (error message below):

```
 Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 authenticationrequired'))'
```

The tricky part is that user's password has an '@' in the middle, I'm wondering if it's messing the syntax (as the system understands the proxy address is right after the first '@').

We tried to escape the @ from the password with: @ and also using %40, and even \%40. None of them worked.

Also tried to SET a variable to pass the proxy URL with the credentials to overcome the command line chars read, but didn't work as well.

Any suggestions?

Comment: if you leave off the username:password@ part of the URL, does it prompt for a un and pw when you run the command?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050877/url-username-with claims that %40 should work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL: Username with @](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050877/url-username-with)

Comment: 1. It doesn't prompt pw and un on the command line, just state the connection error msg
2. %40 should work, indeed. I'm wondering if it's actually the pwd causing trouble. But not sure how to troubleshoot the proxy connection from pip.

Answer (score -4):

[SOLVED]
I had to ask the user to change the password and then it worked out.

Comment: To be honest, this can't be the solution. Pip needs to provide a better way for entering username and password.