# Escaping a lot of characters in password for HTTP Basic auth

Tags: urlencode

I have this user: PpStRoNg

And this password: #%&wL1@*tU123zv

This host:192.168.137.9

And this port: 8090

But I put this in the browser, it completely fails to read the URL:

`http://PpStRoNg:#%&wL1@*tU123zv@192.168.137.9:8090/dsp/app`

It rewrites to this

`http://ppstrong/#%&wL1@*tU123zv@192.168.137.9:8090/dsp/app`

How can make it work with such amount of special characters (`%` and `@` within the password)? I've been trying multiple options with percent-encoding `%` escaping options like:

`http://PpStRoNg%3A#%&wL1@*tU123zv%40192.168.137.9:8090/dsp/app`

Keeping the password intact, but doesn't work either.

Same happens if I try other options like `rtsp://` with the same user and password combo.

EDIT:

Tested

`http://PpStRoNg:%23%25%26wL1%40*tU123zv@192.168.137.9:8090/dsp/app`

And seems to work

Although tested

`rtsp://PpStRoNg:%23%25%26wL1%40*tU123zv@192.168.137.9:8090/dsp/app`

In VLC and it doesn't recognize the URL.

`` live555 error: Failed to connect with rtsp://PpStRoNg:%23%25%26wL1%40*tU123zv@192.168.137.9:8090/dsp/app core error: open of `rtsp://PpStRoNg:%23%25%26wL1%40*tU123zv@192.168.137.9:8090/dsp/app' failed ``

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL: Username with @](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050877/url-username-with)

Comment: Yes I think the idea is to encode the password, not the other characters

Comment: I've tried encoding withthe RTSP stream in VLC and says:
```live555 error: Failed to connect with rtsp://PpStRoNg:%23%25%26wL1%40*tU123zv@192.168.137.9:8090/dsp/app
core error: open of `rtsp://PpStRoNg:%23%25%26wL1%40*tU123zv@192.168.137.9:8090/dsp/app' failed```